# UIDatePicker: While selecting date, it jumps to any random date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have been trying to fix this issue since so long but did not find any way to sort this out.

When I'm trying to select a year sometimes the year component of the date picker jumps to a random year. (The same thing happens with date and month selection)

The data picker is contained in a `UIView` and I have created an `IBOutlet` for it.

```
- (void)setupforBirthdates {

[self.dtPicker setDatePickerMode: UIDatePickerModeDate];


NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents * comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear: -17];
NSDate * maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
[comps setYear: -50];
NSDate * minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: NSCalendarMatchStrictly];

[self.dtPicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
[self.dtPicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[self.dtPicker setDate:maxDate];

}
```

**ISSUE** See the below image...

[image]

I thought that it may be due to some 3rd party libraries this is happening. I have the following pod in my project

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces' 
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.3.0'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Any help/suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I what to restrict user to select birth year from 17 to 50 year only so the `minDate` will be 17 years back from current year
`maxDate` will be 50 years back from the current year

**The issue is also coming if I don't set `minDate` and `maxDate`**

**Tested the following case too**

> - I just drag and drop new date picker on screen. I did not set any min/max date, nor connect an IBOutlet and I run app and when I scroll to any date the same issue is coming
> - You will be surprised that I have created a custom date picker using `UIPickerView` and the issue is still there.
> - When I have created a new demo project and copy pasted the code in demo project then this issue is not coming. I've tested it many times on demo project the issue is not coming.

The following func. is called when I change the date in date picker.

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

  self.txtBirthday.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat  stringFromDate:self.dtPicker.date]];

}
```

Comment: What iOS version do you use?

Comment: Xcode 10.3, iOS version 12.4! (using simulator)

Comment: show the code of `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Comment: What is your ` toDate` ?? Please show us value of maxdate and minDate

Comment: Can you reproduce it on any iOS 12.4 simulator?

Comment: @RomanPodymov, it is happening in real device too. I've tested it on iPhone 6+ and 6s+.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated the question

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I've updated the question

Comment: @Mahendra - where you created this I mean where u called this method `datePickerValueChanged`

Comment: Can you share project codebase if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange thing is that for the When I just put(drag & drop) `UIDatePicker` View on a screen just to test its scrolling issue. When I scroll date time picker view then also it was scrolling at random location.

I feel that it is the issue with third party library.

After many hours of debugging and trail-run, I finally found the third party library which was the source of this issue.

Actually is was the category name is `UITableView+SPXRevealAdditions`.

When I removed it `UIDatePicker` is working fine and when I re-added the issue is started occurring.

It is really very strange but It worked for me.:D

**Update:**

I wanted the that 3rd party too. So what I did id added a dummy pan gesture in `viewDidLoadMethod:`.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *p = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:nil action:@selector(doNothing)];
[self.dtPicker addGestureRecognizer:p];
```

and the dummy method.

```
- (void)doNothing {
    printf("do nothing");
}
```

This solved my problem and Now the `UIDatePicker` is working fine and also third party library too...cheers...:D.

Comment: Answering your own question and not adding proper information in the question and downvoting to working answers are not acceptable by community. -1

Answer (score -1):

You can check whenever your picker want to change the label value by comparing it with the min and max date, here the code *please swap the Ascending and descending if my code do wrong

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {   
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate * maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
[comps setYear: -50];
    NSDate * minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
    NSDate * curDate = self.dtPicker.date;
    if(([curDate compare:minDate] == NSOrderedAscending)&& ([curDate compare:maxDate] == NSOrderedDescending)){
      self.txtBirthday.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:self.dtPicker.date]];
    }

}
```

Comment: its not about setting date from date picker. When I scroll year in date picker view it sometimes jumps to random year as you see in above image. This issue the issue. Why is it scrolling to at random location?

Comment: Have you tried the code? Handling when the label changed is better than nothing.
I have checked your pods. @Mahendra

Check your collectionview pod feature
pod 'RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout' --> Reorder cells by long pressing and dragging it !

Try to remove or disable that pod when testing on this feature

Comment: Yes, I tried your code but it does not solve the asked question and let me know you that removing `RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout` has no effect on date picker view.

Answer (score -2):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.configureDatePicker()


    }


    private func configureDatePicker() {

        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        // 17 years less
        let minimumDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: -17, to: Date())
        // 50 years max. 17 + 33 = 50
        let maximumDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: -50, to: Date())
        self.datePicker.minimumDate = minimumDate
        self.datePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate
    }


    @IBAction func onDatePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

        let dateFormtter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormtter.dateStyle = .medium
        self.label.text = dateFormtter.string(from: sender.date)
    }
}
```

This code works fine without any issue. I think you have some issue in your code. UIDatePicker is resetting in some places.

Comment: @Mahendra why downvoted. You have not given proper information. There is a problem in your code. This is a working code. Please remove downvote

Comment: just downvote this post, leave his alone @mahbaleshwarhegde

Comment: I'm able to get the proper date from date picker. The issue is jump of the date picker...can you provide any other solution. You code is just for the configure and get date from the date picker which I already did and working fine.

Comment: Even my answer is downvoted without any reason...do you have any explanation?